# gwt - servlet path + url

Tags: gwt, servlets

I need to read data from an xml file that is under the WAR directory.
I'm using `RequestBuilder` for creating the `GET` request.
It looks like this:

```
   RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,"customerRecord.xml");  
   try {  
        requestBuilder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {  
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {  
                requestFailed(exception);  
            }  
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,Response   response) {  
                renderXML(response.getText());  
            }  
        });  
    } catch (RequestException ex) {  
        requestFailed(ex);  
    }
```

Now, the thing is that I don't want to load all of the data. I want to send a parameter that   tells the server which part to bring, (let's say - how many lines of data) and then override the doGet method of the servlet and deal with the parameter.
I have 2 questions:
1) how do I declare the path of the servlet? where is the connection between the servlet and the request??
2) What do I write in the url of the `RequestBuilder` (instead of "customerRecord.xml")?  do I need to refer to the servlet there or I can keep it like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be You mean GWT Service?

You need to create 2 interfaces - Service and ServiceAsync and implementation of Service in server package (on same level as client package). Then You define implementation as servlet (in my JBoss 7.1 it just annotation. in older version servlet mapping):

```
@WebServlet(name="YourService", urlPatterns={"/%module%/YourService"})
public class YourServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements YourService
```

in Your modeule.xml write:

```
<servlet path="/YourService" class="org.name.YourServiceImpl"/>
```

and in the end You can call this service from Your code

```
YourService.App.getInstance().getSomething(new AsyncCallback<Collection<Something>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            new MessagePopup("Error: " + caught.getMessage()).center();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Collection<Something> result) {

        }
    });
```

Interfaces You can create from Your beloved IDE. It's much simpler)

One think which still bothering me - I cannot specify path for servlet in another module.

Comment: found solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284190/gwt-calling-rpc-service-inside-another-module